# C++ Builder XE not linking all runtime DLLs

Tags: dll, vcl, static-linking, c++builder-xe

When I compile my project with the option to exclude runtime packages (to do a static library linking) everything goes fine.

But when I run my application on a C++ Builder "virgin" (no packages installed) it won't start and shows the following error:

```
The program can't start because CC32110MT.DLL is missing from your computer...
```

The CC32110MT.DLL is signed as a `Embarcadero RAD Studio C++ Multi-thread RTL (WIN/VCL MT)`
Any ideas of how to fix this other than copy the DLL to the target system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++Builder, you have to disable *both* the Dynamic RTL *and* Runtime Packages in order to produce a fully statically-linked executable (in Delphi, there is no Dynamic RTL). You have only disabled the latter, but not the former yet.

Comment: Duh... Yea I remember that option now... Thanks for reminding me :)